# Deleting rows in a table with Linq to SQL

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, linq-to-sql

I have a sports database with a table groupmembers which have the fields ID, groupID and memberID. I get the memberID from a textbox called txtRemoveGroupMember and the groupID from a checkboxlist. Now I want to delete the rows which have both the groupID and the memberID.
I have tried this code:

```
foreach(ListItem listItem in cblRemoveMemberFromGroup.Items)
{
       int memberid = Convert.ToInt32(txtRemoveGroupMember.Text);
       int groupid = Convert.ToInt32(listItem.Value);

       var removeFromGroup = from gm in dataContext.GroupMembers
            where (gm.memberID == memberid) && (gm.groupID == groupid)
            select gm;

       dataContext.GroupMembers.DeleteOnSubmit(removeFromGroup);
       dataContext.SubmitChanges();
}
```

But I get this error:

> Error 7 Argument 1: cannot convert from 'System.Linq.IQueryable<GSI_side.GroupMember>' to 'GSI_side.GroupMember'

And this error:

> Error 6 The best overloaded method match for 'System.Data.Linq.Table<GSI_side.GroupMember>.DeleteOnSubmit(GSI_side.GroupMember)' has some invalid arguments

Hope someone can help me figure this out!

Comment: DeleteOnSubmit requires an object of type GroupMember and the linq query returns IQueryable. That's why are getting the error. Try using removeFromGroup.ToList() instead.

Comment: For Entity Framework users landing here, see [ExecuteUpdate and ExecuteDelete](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/performance/efficient-updating?tabs=ef7#use-executeupdate-and-executedelete-when-relevant).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You have to call .ToList()

```
var items = removeFromGroup.ToList();
foreach (var item in items)
  dataContext.GroupMembers.DeleteOnSubmit(item);
```

For batch deletes I use [this](https://terryaney.wordpress.com/2008/04/14/batch-updates-and-deletes-with-linq-to-sql/), because LINQ to SQL first loads the entire data which is going to be deleted, then it does the deletes each by each.

https://terryaney.wordpress.com/2008/04/14/batch-updates-and-deletes-with-linq-to-sql/

https://github.com/longday/LINQ-to-SQL-Batch-Updates-Deletes

Comment: See @JeremyWiggins's answer, there is a DeleteAllOnSubmit() method.

Comment: These links are dead now, can you point to a new location or preferably explain what they say?

Comment: @AdrianIftode Thanks!

Comment: Can we somehow delete without loading the entire data?

Answer (score 9):

`removeFromGroup` is still of type `IQuerable`.

You need to specify an actual `GroupMember` to delete.

You could use

```
GroupMember removeFromGroup = (from gm in dataContext.GroupMembers
                               where (gm.memberID == memberid) && (gm.groupID == groupid)
                               select gm).SingleOrDefault();


dataContext.GroupMembers.DeleteOnSubmit(removeFromGroup);
dataContext.SubmitChanges();
```

Alternatively, if your query returns a collection (from the looks of it, it won't since you are filtering by `memberId`) you could use

```
List<GroupMember> removeFromGroup = (from gm in dataContext.GroupMembers
                                     where (gm.memberID == memberid) && (gm.groupID == groupid)
                                     select gm).ToList();


dataContext.GroupMembers.DeleteAllOnSubmit(removeFromGroup);
dataContext.SubmitChanges();
```

Answer (score 3):

```
var listToRemove=(from a in DB.Table
             where a.Equals(id)
             select a).ToList();

DB.Table.DeleteAllOnSubmit(listToRemove);
DB.SubmitChanges();
```

Comment: Will this execute a SELECT before the DELETE query or will it automagically be converted to `DELETE FROM DB.Table WHERE a = :id`? Upd.: judging by the implementation of `DeleteAllOnSubmit`, it will first execute SELECT to fetch entries and then iterate over them in code and delete one by one =/

Answer (score 0):

Guess I'll be that guy. The only way to do that in a performant way, without an excess SELECT preceding the DELETE, is to [use raw SQL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.linq.datacontext.executecommand?view=netframework-4.8.1):

```cs
foreach(ListItem listItem in cblRemoveMemberFromGroup.Items)
{
    int memberid = Convert.ToInt32(txtRemoveGroupMember.Text);
    int groupid = Convert.ToInt32(listItem.Value);

    dataContext.ExecuteCommand(
        " DELETE FROM group_members gm" + 
        " WHERE gm.memberID = @p0 AND gm.groupID = @p1",
        memberid, groupid
    );
}
```

Answer for people who don't consider 2 query round-trips in place of 1 a justified tradeoff for coding convenience.