# System.Linq.Dynamic.ParseException: '.' or '(' expected - VS2012 ERROR

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

I have trying to run the following code:

```
 [TestMethod]
 [TestCleanup]
 public void TestMethod3()
 {
      using (var context = new CorporateDWTestEntities1())
      {
          //Deleting every row within the OLE_DB_Destination1 table.
          var query = from c in context.SRS_Ticket_Transaction_Stage select c;
          query.Delete();
          context.SaveChanges();
      }
 }
```

however when it runs, I recieve an error message that states:

> "Message:Test method Integration_Services_Tests.UnitTest1.TestMethod3
>   threw exception: System.Linq.Dynamic.ParseException: '.' or '('
>   expected Test cleanup method
>   Integration_Services_Tests.UnitTest1.TestMethod3 threw exception.
>   System.Linq.Dynamic.ParseException:
>   System.Linq.Dynamic.ParseException:'.' or ')' expected."

Does anybody know what this means and how to overcome it?

Comment: I'm guessing that this might be a SQL syntax issue. Can you determine the actual SQL select statement generated by this Linq statement?

Answer (score 0):

[According to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9503008/deleting-rows-in-a-table-with-linq-to-sql), you might need to load all of the records into memory, then call `context.SRS_Ticket_Transaction_Stage.DeleteOnSubmit()` for each item:

```
[TestMethod]
[TestCleanup]
public void TestMethod3()
{
    using (var context = new CorporateDWTestEntities1())
    {
        //Deleting every row within the OLE_DB_Destination1 table.
        var query = from c in context.SRS_Ticket_Transaction_Stage select c;
        var records = query.ToList();

        foreach(var record in records) 
        {
            context.SRS_Ticket_Transaction_Stage.DeleteOnSubmit(record);
        }
        context.SubmitChanges();
    }
}
```